# Retain URL With Slashes And Redirect To File

Tags: htaccess, masking

This has probably been answered several times but I can quite find the exact answer im looking for, I've tried a variety of examples but none do what I need.

I'm trying to mask a URL to a one file that has slashes in it, for example.

```
https://<mydomain>.com/your-in-country/united-kingdom >> /?p=12425&country=united-kingdom
```

right now I have the following:

```
RewriteRule ^your\-in\-country/united\-kingdom$ /?p=12425&country=united-kingdom [L,QSA]
```

But that just redirects to the page I'm trying to mask and you end up seeing the un masked URL.

The goal is to save the effort of making multiple pages and have one page dynamically generated based off the country.

I've done something similar with a URL that doesn't have any slashes.

I.e

```
RewriteRule  ^page-1$ page.php?area=1
```

which works fine, its only when I start adding slashed that it gets a bit more complicated.

Update** I am working with WordPress and the other rules including this one is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^your\-in\-country/united\-kingdom$ /?p=12425&country=united-kingdom [L,QSA]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: The slashes have no special meaning here, so dwelling on the slashes is a red herring and should not make this any more "complicated". You have an erroneous _space_ before the `$` in the rule you posted - is that just a typo in your question? "But that just redirects to the page" - there is no "redirect" here, so you may have a conflict with another rule or you are seeing a cached response? What is the HTTP status code of the redirect? What is the file that actually handles the request? You should be rewriting to the file, not the directory. What other directives do you have?

Comment: The target URL in your rule is also different to your example... you are using a `p` URL parameter, whereas your example is using `page_id`, with a different value?

Comment: "The slashes have no special meaning here" - Unless `/your-in-country/united-kingdom` also happens to map to a physical directory?!

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for the info I have updated the question to give a bit more context and corrected the code examples accordingly, It maybe redirecting because of the WordPress htacess ruling beneath this one that I didn't add in the example.